# Filming via iPhone in clubs in Atlanta

Tags: usa, photography, nightlife, atlanta

I would like to ask if filming/taking pictures using your iPhone is OK in clubs in Atlanta (Georgia, USA) or is it prohibited.

Comment: Is this a serious question?

Comment: Rules for private establishments are set by private establishments and more likely then not your filming will end up in a broken iphone and a shiner.  Not to mention that your question is monumentally off topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not travel related.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this really is off topic.  If someone asked if it was permissible to take pictures inside the Taj Mahal, for instance, I expect the question would be permitted. (That's not to say I think it's a great question...)

Comment: @Flimzy First off Taj Mahal (if it's not a hotel or strip club you're referring to) would be a widely known location with a lot of information about it.  Strip clubs like any private establishment is a different story and rules vary and are only known to the patrons of the establishments.  Secondly I don't think that questions on shooting "amateur softcore" is a valid for a travel site...

Comment: @Karlson everybody likes porn. Unless he/she is asexual. It's natural.

Comment: @Derfder I can't say I disagree but it's still nothing to do with travel...

Comment: @Karlson I disagree. A lot of people travel because of romance, short-term, long-term sex/relationships, visiting spas, massages, erotic massages, brothels, strip clubs etc. It's natural and part of our lives and also when we travel.

Comment: @Derfder Romance and sex is one thing.  Porn is quite different...

Comment: @Karlson You can find the lover in a strip club. Why not? Do you see it as a problem to find a sex partner in the strip-club or night club in general? Btw. in most of the strip-clubs there is just naked dancing. The shows(soft-core/hard-core) are only somethimes and only in some of these facilities. Just to be clear that I am not interested in live "porn" scenes. I like dancers, especially the ethnic curvy women.

Comment: @Karlson: The question isn't (specifically) about porn. It's about taking pictures inside a strip club. He may be taking pictures of dancers, patrons, or the decor. That's really none of our business.

Further, the obscurity of a travel destination has never made a question off-topic before. If he had asked about taking pictures in restaurants in Atlanta, would you feel differently?  On golf courses?  In the airport?

It's easy to be distracted by the sensationalism of a strip club, but that's really not at all what this question is about.

Comment: I have removed the word "strip" from the question and title, in hopes of easing tensions.  This does not in any way change the answer to the question, as all clubs, strip or otherwise, play by the same rules in this context.

Comment: @Karslon Maybe the person is traveling to Atlanta and plans to visit some clubs. Hence it is travel related.

Comment: @Flimzy *If he had asked about taking pictures in restaurants in Atlanta, would you feel differently? On golf courses? In the airport?* - not particularly...

Comment: @Karlson: Well I'm glad to know you're not just picking on strip clubs then.  I still think it should be on-topic.  As a photographer, I often want to know when it's permitted to take photos while traveling.

Comment: Upvoting. The accepted answer feels like common sense to me, but I'm glad that the OP asked here, rather than just going ahead and taking photos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no laws prohibiting the use of still or video cameras in any public places anywhere in the U.S. (There may be situational exceptions--such as secret surveillance, but don't ask the NSA about that).  But every property owner, including the owner or management of strip clubs, has the right to prohibit such actions on their property. And I expect that most exercise that right, and have such policies posted near their entrances.

There are likely exceptions, for instance some friends have posted photos of themselves posing with [Chippendales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chippendales) dancers on Facebook. Clearly the dancers knew their photo was being taken, so permission was granted.

Your best bet is always to ask management before taking pictures or video.